# react print the values inside the sports property

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to print the values inside the sports property.
- so I gave console inside the sports.
- but its throwing syntax error.
  `Syntax error: C:/codebase//src/containers/sports.js: Unexpected token, expected , (367:22)`
- I researched to print the values do I need to put the if conditions inside a method and then call it here.
- or is there anyother simpler way to print the player.west.sports.
- providing my code snippet below.

```or-tag-here
<GeoJSON
   data={West}
   onEachFeature={this.onEachFeature}
   ref="west"
   style={
      map.region === "west" ? this.getNewStyle : this.getWhiteStyle
   }
   sports={
      {console.log(" player.west.sports--->", player.west.sports)}
      map.region === "west" ? (
         player.west.sports
      ) : (
         player.white.sports
      )
   }
/>
```

Comment: What is the `sports` prop supposed to be ? Why not print your stuff outside (above/below) your component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do:

```
sports={(console.log(player.west.sports), (map.region === 'west'
  ? player.west.sports
  : player.white.sports
))}
```

This [takes advantage of the comma operator in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which evaluates two expressions and returns the last one.

But you probably shouldn't `console.log` inside a component property since it's not very readable. If possible log it above your JSX e.g. at the beginning of your render function.

Comment: he probably even wants ``sports={player[map.region].sports}`` or ``sports={player[map.region || "white"].sports}``